# Are there any open source resources for SQL schema design patterns?

Tags: sql, schema-design

I can barely count the number of times I've created a "users" table, similar for "computers" and "customers".  I've tried looking around, but haven't ever seen a resource for modeling these schema that we see over and over again.  It seems like some of these objects should be some-kind-of-solved by now. Is there anything like this?

Comment: To add a little bit.  I've got an opportunity to re-model our legacy database as we migrate away from some old scripts.  We're tracking users, and their working groups.  Supporting systems for some internal discussion boards, as well as modeling the company intranet (about 250 servers).

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen anything like this either and I'm not sure it's necessary.  Yes, there are a lot of similarities but every application is different.  At one point I had built an internal library of some of my more "standard" tables (user is a good example) to use as a jumping point, but I have yet to create two identical tables for different systems.

Thus, I have yet to ever use the library I built because I can write the new table quicker and more error free than I can modify another existing example to work for the current project.

Comment: I actually remember seing a web site on this subject a few months ago, I don't think I saved it to my bookmarks, but anyway I think it focused more on patters few procedure and query writing than normalization...There is even a book on this http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Design-Patterns-Programming-In-Focus/dp/0977671542  don't know hoe helpfull is it..

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the source code of some popular open-source CRM/ERPs, such as OpenERP, though some of them are not great.

These are the top books on data modelling patterns:

Analysis Patterns, Fowler
Data Model Resource Book, vol. 1,2,3, Silverston
Enterprise Model Patterns, Hay
Patterns of Data Modeling, Blaha